# Need If Expression to compare time and date in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a requirement where I need to compare two dates and time,
I am testing few REST APIs where the dates dynamically change after 8:00 AM for example basically my application provides data for 1 day:
If the UTC time is not 8 AM my application will display data for past one day
**"GET data for Assets During 2021-11-28T8:00:00 to 2021-11-29T8:00:00"**
But when UTC time  is more than 8 AM for current date API date will dynamic change to next day
**"GET data for Assets During 2021-11-29T8:00:00 to 2021-11-30T8:00:00"**

I am planning to run a Soak test for 48 hr, if any one can provide a statement to compare, I can use timeshift function to either go to set of APIs when time is still not 8AM ${__timeshift(YYYY-MM-dd,-P1D))T08:00:00 and ${__timeshift(YYYY-MM-dd,P1D)) after 8 AM.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to go for [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) and [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class, something like:

- will execute if current UTC hour is later than 8

  ```
  ${__groovy(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC')).get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > 8,)}
  ```
- will execute if current UTC hour is earlier than 8

  ```
  ${__groovy(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC')).get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) < 8,)}
  ```

should do the trick for you.

More information: [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage)